# Partial inserts with Cassandra and Phantom DSL

Tags: scala, cassandra, phantom-dsl

I'm building a simple Scala Play app which stores data in a Cassandra DB using the Phantom DSL driver for Scala.  One of the nice features of Cassandra is that you can do partial updates i.e. so long as you provide the key columns, you do not have to provide values for all the other columns in the table.  Cassandra will merge the data into your existing record based on the key.

Unfortunately, it seems this doesn't work with Phantom DSL.  I have a table with several columns, and I want to be able to do an update, specifying values just for the key and one of the data columns, and let Cassandra merge this into the record as usual, while leaving all the other data columns for that record unchanged.

But Phantom DSL overwrites existing columns with null if you don't specify values in your insert/update statement.

Does anybody know of a work-around for this?  I don't want to have to read/write all the data columns every time, as eventually the data columns will be quite large.

FYI I'm using the same approach to my Phantom coding as in these examples:

https://github.com/thiagoandrade6/cassandra-phantom/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/cassandra/phantom/modeling/model/GenericSongsModel.scala

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be great to see some code, but partial updates are possible with phantom. Phantom is an immutable builder, it will not override anything with null by default. If you don't specify a value it won't do anything about it.

```
database.table.update.where(_.id eqs id).update(_.bla setTo "newValue")
```

will produce a query where only the values you've explicitly set to something will be set to null. Please provide some code examples, your problem seems really strange as queries don't keep track of table columns to automatically add in what's missing.

**Update**

If you would like to delete column values, e.g set them to `null` inside Cassandra basically, phantom offers a different syntax which does the same thing:

```
database.table.delete(_.col1, _.col2).where(_.id eqs id)`
```

Furthermore, you can even delete map entries in the same fashion:

```
database.table.delete(_.props("test"), _.props("test2").where(_.id eqs id)
```

This assumes `props` is a `MapColumn[Table, Record, String, _]`, as the `props.apply(key: T`) is typesafe, so it will respect the keytype you define for the map column.

Comment: Thanks, Flavian.  My code is in flux right now, and it's a bit more complicated than the sample app I linked to above, so I can't easily drop it into this post. However, I am now wondering if I can get around the problem by declaring the columns as Options in my Scala/Phantom code, as it might be that my Scala data classes are the problem.  If this doesn't work, I'll try your update method instead.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Duh. I think the problem is that I'm using an insert to do my update. In Cassandra this works fine because Cassandra treats it as an upsert anyway, and it's good for my use case where I don't need to care if the record already exists or not because I'm only writing the key and one or two specific fields: the default Cassandra behaviour is what I want. But it looks like Phantom expects you to do an update or an insert explicitly, depending on whether the key already exists. I'll try using the update, as Flavian suggested, and see what happens.

Comment: update(_.bla setTo "newvalue") no longer works in phantom 1.27.0. It looks like only modify(_.bla setTo "newvalue") is available. However, it won't update columns with null values which is the problem here.

Comment: Hi @yang, please flag this as a bug on GitHub, and desribe the use case in more detail. In the mean time, you can use `database.table.delete(_.column).where(_.bla eqs "bla")` to achieve the same thing, set columns to `null`.

Comment: Hi @yang have you seen my update to this? It's already available.

Comment: @flavian no I haven't. Where is the update? or which version?

Comment: @yang Read my answer again, with the update in bold, you can update columns and set them to null using: `database.table.delete(_.col1, _.col2).where(_.id eqs id)`.

Comment: I tried `update.where(_.id eqs id).update(_.bla setTo "someValue").future` . I got this: value update is not a member of com.websudos.phantom.builder.query.UpdateQuery[models.security.AuthInfo,models.security.Auth,com.websudos.phantom.builder.Unlimited,com.websudos.phantom.builder.Unordered,com.websudos.phantom.builder.Unspecified,com.websudos.phantom.builder.Chainned,shapeless.HNil]. I can only use `update.where(_.id eqs id).modify(_.bla setTo "some").future` which throws exception when the column bla is null.

Comment: @yang Just use the delete syntax I pointed to above, it does the same thing, sets columns to `null` for all matches of the `where` clause, it doesn't delete entire rows. Try it in `cqlsh`.

Comment: @flavian I don't understand. I do not want to delete a column, nor set the column value to `null`. I want to update or change the value of the column to a specific string, not `null`. How is delete the same as setting it to some value?

Comment: @yang You should be using optional columns, phantom does not support columns being `null` without them.