# How to use phantom dsl's optional columns?

Tags: scala, cassandra, phantom-dsl

This question related to the previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37072926/partial-inserts-with-cassandra-and-phantom-dsl). But since that question is closed, I have to create a separate one.
The use case is this:  I have a table with 5 columns. When creating a record, only 2 columns are required. Later on users will be adding more information to the same record. e.g., a user table with the following structure: id | phone | email | credit | level. When a user registers, I only need their email address. The user will be created with an id and email. later on, users want to add phone#, credits, system also will update level when this user has enough credits. 
I created a

```
case class User(id:UUID, phone:Option[String], email:Option[String], 
    credit:Option[Double], level:Option[String]
```

also I have

```
sealed class Users extends CassandraTable[Users, User] {
    object id extends UUIDColumn(this) with PartitionKey[UUID]

    object phone extends OptionalStringColumn(this)

    object email extends OptionalStringColumn(this)

    object credit extends OptionalDoubleColumn(this)

    object level extends OptionalStringColumn(this)

    def fromRow(row: Row): User = {
        User(id(row), phone(row), email(row), credit(row), level(row))
    }
}
```

Am I using the optional columns right?
How should I proceed on the use cases where users are updating one or more specific columns? I tried the update method like this

```
def updateUser(u: User): Future[ResultSet] = {
    update.where(_.id eqs u.id).modify(_.phone setTo u.phone)
      .and(_.email setTo u.email)
      .and(_.credit setTo u.credit)
      .and(_.level setTo u.level)
      .consistencyLevel_=(ConsistencyLevel.QUORUM)
      .future()
  }
```

this method doesn't work well since you have to read the table from the id and create a User object with existing column values and adding new values and then update the record. It is also not practical to write a lot of conditions in the update method. If I have a lot of columns and each column can be updated separately, I will have to write a huge list of possible combinations of values. The following method may work:

```
    if(u.phone != None) update.where(_.id eqs u.id).modify(_.phone setTo u.phone).future
    if(u.email != None) update.where(_.id eqs u.id).modify(_.email setTo u.email).future
    if(u.credit != None) update.where(_.id eqs u.id).modify(_.credit setTo u.credit).future
    ......
```

But I am not sure it is a good practice since it will be a nightmare if you want to handle update failure on each update. How should I use the optional column to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 3):

As of Phantom 1.28.5, what you want is achievable using the new `setIfDefined` operator, which will give you what you want, an `Update` clause that only accounts for options that are defined.

Your update method now becomes:

```
def updateUser(u: User): Future[ResultSet] = {
  update.where(_.id eqs u.id).modify(_.phone setTo u.phone)
    .and(_.email setIfDefined u.email)
    .and(_.credit setIfDefined u.credit)
    .and(_.level setIfDefined u.level)
    .consistencyLevel_=(ConsistencyLevel.QUORUM)
    .future()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Queries in Phantom are classes until you realize them by calling something like `.future` or `.one`.  At the lowest level you can build up a query by using `match` or `if` statements...

```
def updateUser(u: User): Future[ResultSet] = {
  val baseQuery = update.where(_.id eqs u.id).modify(_.phone setTo u.phone)

  val query2 = u.email match {
    case Some(email) => baseQuery.and(_.email setTo email)
    case None => baseQuery // don't do anything if none!
  }

  // ...

  query5.future()
}
```

That's kind of ugly and tedious but it does work.

I ran into a similar situation when I had a model which had a property of type `Either`.  I ended up writing a little extension for the PhantomDSL which I should probably formalize and commit back, but it cleans up the above mess nicely.  It was for `INSERT` but this should give you an idea of how easy it is if you wanted to do the same for `UPDATE`.  The tricky part would be handling the `modify` vs. `and`, but I'm sure digging around in the source they are doing the same operation under the covers and the difference is only aesthetic.

In use:

```
table.insert
  .value(_.foo, "foo")
  .valueOpt(_.bar, Some("bar"))
  .valueIf(_.buz, x, x.nonEmpty)
  .matchOn(someEither) {
    case (Left(Person(name, age), insert) => insert
      .value(_.personName, name) 
      .value(_.personAge, age)
    case (Right(Company(name, employeeCount), insert) => insert
      .value(_.companyName, name)
      .value(_.companyAge, age)
  }
  .future()
```

Source:

```
class RichInsert[T <: CassandraTable[T, _], R, S <: ConsistencyBound, P <: HList](val insert: InsertQuery[T,R,S,P]) {

  def value[RR](col: T => AbstractColumn[RR], value: RR): RichInsert[T,R,S,P] =
    new RichInsert(insert.value(col, value))

  def valueIf[RR](col: T => AbstractColumn[RR], value: RR, clause: => Boolean): RichInsert[T,R,S,P] = {
    if (clause) RichInsert(insert.value(col, value))
    else this
  }

  def valueOpt[RR](col: T => AbstractColumn[RR], value: Option[RR]): RichInsert[T,R,S,P] = {
    value match {
      case Some(rr) => RichInsert(insert.value(col, rr))
      case None => this
    }
  }

  def matchOn[A](value: A)(pf: PartialFunction[(A, RichInsert[T,R,S,P]), RichInsert[T,R,S,P]]) =
    if (pf.isDefinedAt((value, this))) pf.apply((value, this))
    else this
}

object RichInsert {
  def apply[T <: CassandraTable[T, _], R, S <: ConsistencyBound, P <: HList](insert: InsertQuery[T,R,S,P]): RichInsert[T,R,S,P] =
    new RichInsert(insert)
}

implicit def insertQueryToRichInsert[T <: CassandraTable[T, _], R, S <: ConsistencyBound, P <: HList](insert: InsertQuery[T,R,S,P]): RichInsert[T,R,S,P] =
  RichInsert(insert)
```

Edit --

One thing I forgot to mention, is that when you read back the data instead of doing `column(row)` do `column.parse(row)`.  You'll get a `Try[A]` and from there you could do `column.parse(row).toOption`.  I can't remember but I think there might be a function there to check if the column is defined before you try and read it so you don't have to use exceptions for flow control™.

Comment: The `column.parse(row).toOption` is automatically added for you when you chose to use `Optional` column. Something like a collection will also automatically default to empty without needing `Optional`.